# Listview items between space in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**This is my listview class**

```
public class ListViewClass : ListView
{        
    public ListViewClass ()
    {    
        var cell = new DataTemplate(typeof(ViewCellClass));                
        ItemTemplate = cell;
        SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;
        this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["commonBottomMarginThickness"];
        HasUnevenRows = true;                    
    }            
}
```

**I attached the screenshot. how to put space between the listview items above and below.**

[image]

Comment: I think you can insert a stackLayout with padding inside `ViewCellClass`

Comment: Padding is working fine. Thanks! Diego Rafael Souza

Answer (score 1):

Add the value `Transparent` to your SeparatorColor property.

Like this:

```
public ListViewClass ()
{    
    var cell = new DataTemplate(typeof(ViewCellClass));                
    ItemTemplate = cell;
    SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;
    SeparatorColor = Color.Transparent;
    this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["commonBottomMarginThickness"];
    HasUnevenRows = true;                    
}
```